# New Kitchen extractor fan stopped working

Tags: kitchens, fans, hood

Brand new kitchen extractor hood fitted last week. The lights still work, but the fan won’t turn on, so I assume not a fuse problem.

The extractor duct was about 5mm too large to fit in the top of the hood, so I squeezed it in best I could and used duct tape to seal it; might this cause an issue? Or is it just a dud? (Cheapest hood from screwfix, had good reviews).[1](https://www.screwfix.com/p/clihs60-integrated-cooker-hood-600mm-grey/640FH?tc=ET8&ds_kid=92700046986170840&ds_rl=1241687&ds_rl=1245250&ds_rl=1245725&ds_rl=1245250&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIpPqU7vLL8QIVxYFQBh1JcQCREAQYAiABEgIPx_D_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Comment: I should add that the fan did work for about a week.

Comment: Simplest - remove, and return to Screwfix. Whatever the problem is, it's not doing the job you purchased it for.

Answer (score 10):

Squeezing the extractor duct to fit into the hood shouldn't cause an issue unless you bent the fan housing and it's binding. Check that the fan spins freely and also check your electrical connections, one might have vibrated loose. Check the fan to switch connectors as well, they are usually spade connectors and could have started working loose during installation.